# How to change the display property of the style attribute of an element using Selenium and Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, display

I am not able to change the `style` in `div` section using selenium **Java**. Please see picture I need to change the `style` of `div` which contain `id` is "`navbar`".

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image: html]

This is my code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = null; 
  if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) 
  { js
 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
  }

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]"));
System.out.println(element);
//js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:none')", element);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'none'", element);
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the `display` property of *style* attribute as **`block`** you can use:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('navbar').style.display='block';");
```